# Facebook Messenger Chat - The CustomerChat plugin is no longer part of the main Facebook SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger-bot

i have a problem with posting the messenger plugin on the website.
I generate code using the Facebook function in the menu Settings-> Messenger Platform on the company profile.
I added the domain of my website to 'White List'.
The following code is generated, which we place immediately after opening the < BODY > tag in the HTML code of the site:

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.2'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="267615313329074"
  logged_in_greeting="My message"
  logged_out_greeting="My message">
</div>
```

An error appears in the console:

```
##########################
#  The CustomerChat plugin is no longer part of the main Facebook SDK.
#  To continue using it please use the correct SDK URL,
#  meaning replace sdk.js with sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js.
#  For more details see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/sdk
##########################
```

The link seems to have the form that they recommend on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/sdk

Does anyone know how to improve the code pasted on the website?

Comment: Is this the only place where you embed any SDK, or is there maybe another place where it still embeds the “basic” one? Can you try to embed the en_US version instead of the Polish one, and see if that changes anything? (Maybe they have not fully made the switch for all localized versions, forgot to remove something from this particular one, …)

Comment: Yes, there was a reference in the code to the old version of sdk. I removed and messenger works.
Thank You very much! :)